# An easy way to completely (Entities, tags, comments etc.) read an xml document with unknown structure in php?

Tags: php, xml

I'm just stuck on a problem that I didn't think was that difficult to solve.

I am developing a website where xml files can be uploaded and downloaded. The xml files have to be read completely and I want to write the information into a database.

There are a limited number of possible structures but it is not defined which structure is present in an uploaded document. This has to be recognized by the system itself. Ideally it should be possible to recreate the uploaded document from the entries in the database.

All elements of the documentation should be read. Particularly important:

- Named entities
- All tags, attributes and values
- Comments and which element they are above
- The use of the entities in the document should also be stored in the database.

I have attached two sample documents. The files are in reality more extensive. I just wanted to present the problem as simply as possible.

Already for a tip which PHP class/library/function(s) can fulfill my requirements, I would be very grateful. I've been looking all Sunday, but I've only been moving in circles…

I'm not a professional PHP developer, that's just a recreational project. Please be gracious if the question is easy to answer.

inhabitants.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE inhabitants [
  <!ENTITY cName "Ultra Long Surname">
]>
<inhabitants>
    <inhabitant alias="bob">Bob &cName;</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="tom">Tom &cName;</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="tim">Tim Short</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="leo">Leo Short</inhabitant>
</inhabitants>
```

streets.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<districts>
    <district name="d1">
        <street size="small">Nameless street</street>
        <street size="long">Sutton Lane</street>
    </district>
    <district name="d2">
        <!-- Not explored -->
        <street size="unknown">Street of Death</street>
    </district>
</districts>
```

My last attempt, or what I've already found out:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('files/inhabitants.xml');

// How to get "Ultra Long Surname" ?
echo 'Value of "cName": '.$dom->doctype->entities->item(0)->nodeValue;
// Output: "Value of "cName": "

// How do I get a list of all tags?

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('inhabitant') as $inhabitant){
    if ($inhabitant instanceof DOMElement){
        echo $inhabitant->getAttribute('alias');
        echo ' - ';
        echo $inhabitant->nodeValue;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
/*
 * Output:
 *
 * bob - Bob Ultra Long Surname
 * tom - Tom Ultra Long Surname
 * tim - Tim Short
 * leo - Leo Short
 */

// How to get "&cName;" instead of "Ultra Long Surname"?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in an DOM is a node. You found the entity definition already, the entity reference is a node, too. However working on this level will take effort, just because the level of detail. Xpath can help a lot. It allows you to fetch specific nodes.

To get the entity reference you will have to look at the node inside the element.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE inhabitants [
  <!ENTITY cName "Ultra Long Surname">
]>
<inhabitants>
    <inhabitant alias="bob">Bob &cName;</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="tom">Tom &cName;</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="tim">Tim Short</inhabitant>
    <inhabitant alias="leo">Leo Short</inhabitant>
</inhabitants>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//inhabitant') as $inhabitant) {
    echo $inhabitant->getAttribute('alias');
    echo ' - ';
    foreach ($inhabitant->childNodes as $node) {
        echo get_class($node), ": ";
        if ($node instanceof DOMText) {
            echo $node->textContent;
        } elseif ($node instanceof DOMEntityReference) {
            echo $node->nodeName;
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
bob - DOMText: Bob DOMEntityReference: cName 
tom - DOMText: Tom DOMEntityReference: cName 
tim - DOMText: Tim Short 
leo - DOMText: Leo Short
```

I am not sure what you would like to do with an entity reference in a database. Disconnected from a document it will not reference any value.

Fetching a comment preceding a node can be done with Xpath:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<districts>
    <district name="d1">
        <street size="small">Nameless street</street>
        <street size="long">Sutton Lane</street>
    </district>
    <district name="d2">
        <!-- Not explored -->
        <street size="unknown">Street of Death</street>
    </district>
</districts>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//district/street') as $street) {
    echo $street->textContent, ':';
    echo $xpath->evaluate(
        'string(preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][self::comment()])', 
        $street
    );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Nameless street: 
Sutton Lane: 
Street of Death: Not explored
```

#### The Xpath Expression:

- fetch preceding sibling nodes that are not just whitespace
  `preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space(.) != ""]`
- Filtered by position
  `preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1]`
- Filtered for comment nodes
  `preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][self::comment()]`
- Cast into string
  `string(preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space(.) != ""][1][self::comment()])`

Comment: You're my hero! I was able to solve all my problems with your answer (as far as I can see at the moment). The expression was the sticking point for me. I stumbled across this class on Sunday, but the documentation was so thin that I couldn't get any further.

Comment: DOM and Xpath are not PHP specific. They are available in other languages and in modern Browsers (not IE, but Edge). MDN is a good documentation resource for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Answer (score 0):

Use simpleXML.  Its simple and works great.

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

It's also bundled with php since 5.1.x unless explicitly excluded.

Comment: SimpleXML will not provide the requested information. For example the comments.